# git-bash-prompt not displaying correctly with GIT 2.11.0

Tags: git, git-bash

I have used git-bash-prompt with several versions of GIT. Since I installed GIT 2.11.0 the git-bash-prompt functions return âÂ or â for Status symbols. It kinda makes the git-bash-prompt not very helpful. Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue. A pre-release fix is now available https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.11.1.windows-prerelease.1

All reports from the issues pages have reported that it successfully cures the many differing symptoms.

Comment: There is also a pre-release.2 available now. It may be necessary for some users to `set LC_ALL=C` as detailed in GfW issue #1036.